# Operations are needed to compute $Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $n \times  n$ real matrix $A$. How many operations are needed to compute $Ax$.
I start to do the following,

$Ax=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}&\dots &a_{1n} \\
 \vdots  & \ddots &\dots &\vdots  \\
 a_{n1} &\dots &\dots&a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\
 x_2  \\
 x_3 \end{bmatrix}=$
$\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{ j=1} ^n a_{1j}x_j \\ \sum_{ j=1} ^n a_{2j}x_j 
 \\
  \vdots    
  \\ \sum_{ j=1} ^n a_{nj}x_j 
 \end{bmatrix}$
I can not do it with detail to show that the operation is $n(2n-1).$

Answer (score 1):

$2n^2-n$, since there are $n$ products and $n-1$ sums $n$ times. That is, there are $n$ dot products, each of which have, in a sense, $2n-1$ operations.

Comment: how about if multiply

Comment: That's what I mean by products.

Comment: how about if we multiply Ax by any real numbers, what it will be happen for the operation?

Comment: That's not really at issue here.